# ClickOnce application signed, but anti virus show an alert

Tags: visual-studio-2013, clickonce, publish

I publish a C# application with Click Once. I'm using a signed certificate got from StartSSL (Class 2 Code Signing).

The ClickOnce application is downloadable through an IIS server hosted on my own: http://my.dyndns.biz:8090\MyAppName

I tested the installation process on the same PC as the one I use to develop the application and my antivirus (Nod32) stop the download because it think the source is dangerous.

How do I avoid the anti-virus to stop the operation (I don't want to disable it)?

P.S. The publisher of the application is not unknown

Thanks

Comment: If Nod32 considers the entire `dyndns.biz` domain as potentially hostile, your best bet would be to host the code somewhere else.

Comment: You were right. I tested on my GoDaddy basic account (no SSL, juste a regular URL) and I've been able to download the ClickOnce application without antivirus issue... Thanks